# Are we "still in support" if our application targets an old version of the .NET Framework on a modern version of the .NET runtime

Tags: .net

We have a project where we would like to update a projects dependencies to still be under support by Microsoft.

It's a legacy project that is not understood very well, to minimize changes as much as possible I'd like to the app to remain targeting an old version of the .NET Framework - 3.5, while updating the version of the .NET runtime installed - 3.5 -> 4.8.

In this setup, are we still supported by Microsoft?

Comment: Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Maybe I'm being thick, but I can't seem to see the answer to this specific question in that article, I'm wondering specifically about whether targeting old versions of .NET with modern versions of the runtime affects what is in / out of support.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the runtime is what is in support. In any case, both 3.5 and 4.8 are in support for the next few years